# Ember.js and Foundation 4 modal window

Tags: ember.js, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I have two problems with Foundation Reveal and Ember.js.

First, action "close" is not firing. I have any ideas why.

```
#application.js
App.ModalView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "modal",
    title: "",
    classNames: ["reveal-modal"],
    didInsertElement: function () {
        this.$().foundation('reveal', 'open');
    },
    actions: {
        close: function () {
            console.log('close action fired');
            this.destroy();
        }
    },
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        showModal: function () {
            var view = this.container.lookup('view:modal', {title:'Test title'}).append();
        }
    }
});

#index.html

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    <a {{action showModal}}>show modal</a>
</script>



  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modal">
      <h2> {{title}}</h2>
      <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal"  {{action close target="view"}}>&#215;</a>
      <a {{action close target=view}}>Close</a>
  </script>
```

And the second is that i cant set attributes of view while adding it this way:

```
 App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        showModal: function () {
            var view = this.container.lookup('view:modal', {title:'Test title'}).append(); //not setting title
        }
    }
});
```

For second i can't find in documentation how i can set view parameters while adding via lookup.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L4m6v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created project on github for this problem with fixed foundation.reveal.js:
(i didnt find the way to fix foundation.js on jsbin)

I think other libs that making modal have the same problem, so if you'are using jquery-ui you may fix it too.

https://github.com/xjok3rx/ember-modal

Answer (score 1):

Ember doesn't set up the plumbing when you create a view in this manner.

You can build a popup that lives on the application (which is easy to edit and manipulate from anywhere within the application (controllerFor('application') from a route, or needs:['application'] and this.get('controllers.application') from controllers).

Here's a simple JSBin showing this (I didn't spend much time on making it pretty, CSS isn't really a strong suit of mine anyway).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eGIZaxI/1/edit

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  title: "Popup Title",
  description: "You should do something",
  isVisible: true
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },

  actions: {

    hidePopup: function(){
        $(".popup").fadeOut(); 
        this.controllerFor('application').set('isVisible', false);
    },

    showPopup: function(){
        $(".popup").fadeIn();
         this.controllerFor('application').set('isVisible', true);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The pop up would either need to be created in the application template, then using css hide it (off to the side, or display:none).  Then you could use css to show it when necessary.  Or don't use ember for creating the pop up.  In our application we have a mixture of both.  It's a tricky problem in the ember ecosystem.  If you don't understand the first, let me know and I'll see if I can set up an example for you

Comment: If modal will have static content, hiding it by css seems to be good idea, but if i need dynamic content (unique for every call) i don't know how to implement this...

Comment: It really works! I have found the problem in my code - it's foundation lib, after calling $().foundation('reveal', 'open'); all actions unbound from popup, and i can undestand why.. solved by hardcoding and manipulating css visibility styles. Seems to be a bit dirty :(

Comment: I found the problem in Zurb Foundation.js - it was detaching modal to body. Thnx for hints!

Comment: @joker.odessa please add a proper answer to your question, so that others coming across the same problem you did don't get confused.