# EmberJs {{ action }} helper in a view doesn't work

Tags: view, ember.js, action

I'm trying to add bootstrap modals in my ember app. I'd like to be able to add modals, with a specified template and be able to handle actions. I can't get it works. The modal appears, my controller's properties are bound, but i can't handle actions. I don't understand why. I'd really like to be able to trigger modal from anywhere in my controllers and bind actions on them.

My view looks like this:

```
App.ModalView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames:         ['modal fade'],
    attributeBindings:  ['role'],
    role:               'dialog',

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();
        this.$().modal();
        this.$().on('hidden.bs.modal', this.close.bind(this));
    },
    close: function(event) {
        return this.destroy();
    }
});
```

And i instanciate it like this in a random controller:

```
var modal = controller.container.lookup('view:modal');
modal.reopen({
    controller:     this,
    targetObject:   this,
    templateName:   'mymodal'
});

return modal.appendTo('body');
```

My template looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               My modal content
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn green" {{ action "myaction"}}>My Button with an action</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If i try to display some controller properties, it works. But when i click on the button with the "myaction" action nothing happends. Maybe i'm completely wrong about the way to handle modals in my app (i'm pretty new in the Ember's World).
I'm using the last release of ember (1.1.1) and bootstrap 3.

Thanks,

Vinc

Comment: I don't see myaction defined in your view, additionally where did you find the information for creating a view like that?

Comment: I don't have the myaction handler, but i should get the message indicates that nothing handle the "myaction" action :) We have to create views like this or we get an deprecated error (i can found you the link if you want)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. In fact, my app was running into a specific dom element (#app). As i was adding the view to the body, my modale was added "outside" my app ! So, the events bubbling chain was broken. Instead of adding my view to the body, i add it to my application root element and now everything works as expected !

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that the modal method is disconnecting it from the body, which would break your actions.

See also: [Ember.js and Foundation 4 modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481217/ember-js-and-foundation-4-modal-window/19481421#19481421)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access view like this

> var modal = controller.container.lookup('view:modal');

See Wycats comment [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2959#issuecomment-20497404).

Alternatively, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653061/ember-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dialog/18654751#18654751) may help you in instantiating modals

Comment: What is the proper way ? Should i instanciate it with App.ModalView.create() ? if i use create(), i get the following error: DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup] see: http://git.io/EKPpnA

Comment: You need not to create, append or remove views.
Let the framework handle this.

You can use the `render` method, which will handle all these.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested in the gist. Handle the modal opening with event into the Application Route with the "render" method. But at the end, i have a lot of limitations: Can't access my view object. Can't trigger events on this view, can't simply configure my view, have to handle the bootstrap animations stuff by my own, etc... Using a "ModalManager", it gets easier to manager my modals: open / close, etc...